# Granular Excel Pivot Table Security

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I currently produce a report for 5 managers that contains data for each of their employees. The raw data lives in a table in Excel file A, while Excel file B has a pivot table on it connected to the data in file A. I use the manager name as the report filter to list all of their employees data in the pivot table for that manager.

What i am trying to do is prevent the managers from being able to use the report filter to view other manager employee's data. I know I can do this easily by locking the workbook, thereby preventing the manager from using the pivot table at all... the problem arises because I would like the manager to have access to a Slicer to filter by employee name (a row label). If I lock the workbook then the Slicer is not useable, and if I enable "Use PivotTable Reports" then they can access the report filter.

Ideally what I would like is some way to force the data connection between file A and B to call for an update from file A when the report filter is changed (but not the Slicer). Because file A resides only on my PC, the update would fail in the manager's copy of file B.

Does this make any sense? I want to disable the use of the report filter, but still allow the Slicer to filter based on row label...

Comment: Before we get into an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), are you sure you can't use the slicer when locked?  Look at [this thread](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/663169-protecting-worksheet-but-maintaining-slicer-functionality-usability.html) or this [search](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=use%20slicer%20with%20locked%20workbook), does nothing there help?

Comment: I had looked at that before posting, yes - the problem seems to be that protecting a sheet but allowing pivot-table updates is all or nothing - either all filters can be used (report filter or slicer) when "use pivot-table reports" is checked, or none can be.

Comment: since the data for each manager's file is connected to file A, can you just set up a filter in the connection to only show the employees data for that manager. (I know that means modifying each manager's file separately, but it would work).

Comment: Hey Scott - not sure I know enough about data connections to set up a filter on it? I set this one up in file B by going Insert - Pivot-table - Use an External Data Source, and then navigating to file A. Unless your suggestion is to set up separate tabs in file A for each manager... but i would like to not change or edit the source data if at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A functional answer turned out to be fairly easy... I hid the row that included the Report Filter, protected the sheet but allowed pivot table changes, but disallowed most everything else.

So, while the report filter *IS* still there, it's in a hidden row that can never be unhidden by the end user. The Slicer still allows row label filtering.